# How to check processor's vendor in Ruby / Vagrantfile

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile, cpu-architecture

How can I check what is processor's vendor in Ruby / Vagrantfile?
I was looking for universal way, not OS-specific.

It'll be enough to check if it's AMD or Intel - I don't need to know exact model etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `facter` gem

```
 model = Facter.value(:architecture)
```

It will return one of the following: `"x86_64", "amd64", "i386", /parisc/, "hppa", "ia64"`

Comment: To be more specific - to get an exact model I had to use Facter.value(:processor0) - and there was information about vendor there. Thanks!